# How to add hardcoded data to hashmap in android?

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, android-arrayadapter

Hi i wanted to add a hardcoded set of values in hashmap. In that hashmap 5values will be added from web service and i want to add one more data manually. If i do that the last two values showing the same name and details in listview. Iam new to android,So please help me if anybody knows.

I tried the below piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        if (i != 5) {
                            JSONObject c = tsubaki_products.getJSONObject(i);
                            // url_index++;

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String name = c.getString(PRODUCT_NAME);
                            String image = c.getString(PRODUCT_TAB_IMAGE
                                    .replace(" ", "%20"));
                            System.out.println("PRODUCT_NAME-->>" + name);
                            String description = c
                                    .getString(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION);
                            String short_name = c.getString(PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME);
                            short_url = c.getString(PRODUCT_SHORT_URL);

                            // result_url = "," + short_url;
                            /*
                             * category_urls = new
                             * ArrayList<String>(tsubaki_products.length());
                             * 
                             * //description ="";
                             * 
                             * category_urls.add(short_url);
                             * System.out.println("Category"+category_urls);
                             */
                            // array_j=new JSONArray(short_url);
                            // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            /*
                             * for(int j =0;j<short_url.size();i++) { String
                             * prefix = ""; for (String str : short_url) {
                             * sb.append(prefix); prefix = ",";
                             * sb.append(str.toString()); } }
                             */
                            // System.out.println("Short232"+category_urls);
                            // category_urls = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,
                            // String>>();
                            /*
                             * category_urls = new ArrayList<String>();
                             * category_urls.add(short_url);
                             */
                            // category_urls.add(category_map);
                            // category_urls =
                            /*
                             * StringBuffer string_buf = new
                             * StringBuffer(short_url);
                             * string_buf.append(short_url+",");
                             * System.out.println("Short232"+string_buf);
                             */
                            // .replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","")
                            // creating new HashMap
                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(PRODUCT_NAME, name);
                            if (i == 4) {
                                map.put(PRODUCT_NAME,
                                        getString(R.string.slide_head_text6));
                                map.put(PRODUCT_TAB_IMAGE, "cable");
                            } else {
                                map.put(PRODUCT_TAB_IMAGE, image);
                            }

                            map.put(PRODUCT_SHORT_URL, short_url);
                            map.put(PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME, short_name);

                            if (i == 4) { // System.out.println("sfdasgf"+"4");
                                map.put(PRODUCT_NAME,
                                        getString(R.string.slide_head_text6));
                            }
                            // System.out.println("Description" + description);
                            if (description == "null" || description == null) {
                                if (i == 0) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text1));
                                }
                                if (i == 2) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text3));
                                }
                                if (i == 3) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text4));
                                }
                                if (i == 4) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text5));
                                }

                                // Do any stuff
                            } else {
                                if (i == 1) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text2));
                                }
                                if (i == 4) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text5));
                                }
                                if (i == 0) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text1));
                                }
                                if (i == 2) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text3));
                                }
                                if (i == 3) {
                                    map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                            getString(R.string.slide_text4));
                                }/*
                                 * if(i == 5) { map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                 * getString(R.string.slide_text6)); }
                                 */
                                // description =
                                // c.getString(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION).replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","");
                                // map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, description);
                            }
                            // adding HashList to ArrayList

                             productList.add(map);
                        } /*else if (i == 5) {

                            map.put(PRODUCT_NAME,
                                    getString(R.string.slide_head_text7));
                            map.put(PRODUCT_TAB_IMAGE, "clutches");
                            map.put(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                                    getString(R.string.slide_text6));                           
                            // productList.add(map);

                        }*/                                                 

                        // }
                        // productList.add(map);
                        // System.out.println("List" +productList);
                    }
```

Comment: map.put("always_present_key", "always present value"); this should do it and plus its hardcoded

Comment: so how to add one more data in hash map?

Comment: you can use map.put() as many times as you need map.put("second","second");

Comment: iam using loop to add data to hashmap to store values from web service. one more has to be added manually. i tried a lot but cant get a way..

Comment: try to add that value just after your for loop completes

Comment: try this: map.put(i+"", i+"");